# AppleScript executes both If and Else, but only on a network user, not on a local admin

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm trying to modify a local property file for an application, for each of our Network users, who each have local User folders on each client computer. The property file is stored in the local user folder, that I want to do the following with, so this happens on login rather than having to do this manually on a whole lot of users:

1. Check if it has the relevant modifier string already
2. If it does not, append the string to the text configuration file

The following code works perfectly when executed from the admin account: It adds the string if it isn't already there, and if it is, then it displays the Dialog window (That I just have there to debug it)

However, the moment I log on with a Local Network Account, it BOTH displays the Dialog Window AND adds appends the string to the configuration file, and keeps adding a new one for every login. It applies these to the correct file, so the file path is still pointing at the right config file.

I don't understand why the same script would behave like this?

```
    set userName to short user name of (system info)
    set JournalProps to "/Users/" & userName & "/NameOfTheConfigFileHere"
    close access (open for access JournalProps)
    set FontSize to "name_fontsize=18"
    set TheFileContents to paragraphs of (read JournalProps)
    if FontSize is in TheFileContents then
        set DisplayText to "Fontsize already set"
        display dialog DisplayText
    else
        write linefeed & "name_fontsize=18" & linefeed to JournalProps as "utf8" starting at eof
    end if
```

Comment: Could the script be running twice for the network users (appending to the config file the first run, displaying the dialog on the second)? How is the script being triggered?

Comment: The script is triggered on run, and it is triggered together with other content in the same script that shows it only runs once - moving some folders, closing windows etc. 

And even if it ran twice, it should not keep adding the line on third and fourth login - then both runs should encounter the "if is in FileContents" check.

Comment: We obviously can't see the whole script here but properties typically are updated after changes, i.e. each time the script is run. Wouldn't that explain your repeat appending? As an aside, couldn't you test it manually by running and re-running the script without restarting?

Comment: This is basically the whole script - it does one other thing, but I have tested it with removing that one. 

When running the script manually, the behaviour is the same on the administrator account, but you're right, I should test it manually on the user account as well to see what it is actually doing. Don't think it will change the behaviour, which is obviously linked to the network nature of it, but I can see what happens at least.